# WPF DependencyProperty chain notification

Tags: wpf, binding, notifications, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

im exploring WPF world, i find a great example on the web about how to use binding on xml

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37854/How-to-Perform-WPF-Data-Binding-Using-LINQ-to-XML

Now im trying to extends this example: i want to create a "class in the middle" between the `XElement` and the UI and bind all togheder in a chain so, if i have a modification into the xml, then i have the property in the middle class updated then the UI updated too.

Here some code:

This is the class that wrap the `XElement`

```
public class XElementDataProvider : ObjectDataProvider
{
    public XElementDataProvider()
    {
        ObjectInstance = XElement.Load(@"C:\MyFile.xml");
    }

    private static XElementDataProvider instance;


    public static XElementDataProvider Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new XElementDataProvider();
            }
            return instance;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the `MiddleClass`

```
public class MiddleClass : DependencyObject
{


    XElementDataProvider xElementDataProvider;
    XElement myxml;

    public MiddleClass()
    {
                    //here i get my dataprovider
        xElementDataProvider = XElementDataProvider.Instance;
        myxml = xElementDataProvider.Data as XElement;

                    //i bind my internal collection to the Elements...
        Binding binding = new Binding("Elements[book]")
        {
            Source = myxml,
            Mode = BindingMode.Default//here i cant use TwoWay, give me          //back an exeption
        };


        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, XBookListProperty, binding);

                    //just to have confirmation of the adding
        myxml.Changed += new EventHandler<XObjectChangeEventArgs (myxml_Changed);

    }

    void myxml_Changed(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
    {

    }

            //i use a DependencyProperty to have also a change callback
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XBookListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("XBookList", typeof(IEnumerable),
        typeof(MiddleClass),
        new PropertyMetadata(XBookPropertyChanged)
        );


            //here i have a notification only at start but no when i add a new book
    private static void XBookPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MiddleClass middleClass = d as MiddleClass;
        middleClass.XBookPropertyChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void XBookPropertyChanged(IEnumerable old, IEnumerable newValue)
    {

    }
             //this is the propery i finally want to expose to the UI but im not able //to keep updated
    public List<Book> bookList;
    public List<Book> BookList
    {
        get
        {
            return bookList;
        }
        set
        {
            bookList = value;
        }
    }



    //this is my internal list binded to the xml
    private IEnumerable XBookList
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(XBookListProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(XBookListProperty, value);
        }
    }

            //here i try to add a book addind direcly to the xml//i expect a //notification of propery changed...but nothing
    public bool AddBook(string name)
    {

        XElement newWorkSheet = new XElement("Book",
            new XAttribute("Name", name)
            );

        myxml.Add(newWorkSheet);


        return true;
    }
```

Book is a class thar repersents a book, let say it has only a name propery for now.

The UI class misses but it should bind on public `List<Book>` BookList and show books names to the user in a `ListBox`

Enyone knows why i dont recive any notification...or what i have to do to keep the public `List<Book>` BookList synchronized with private `IEnumerable<XBookList>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after many attempts, the only solution I found is this one:

to have notifications when something changes in the `IEnumerable<XBookList>` you need to clear it ad rebind after you modify it.

In this way you have a first, not used notification, about the clear and then another notification about the new set.

Then in the handler you can synchronize the new list with the old one.

```
public bool AddBook(string name)
{

    XElement newWorkSheet = new XElement("Book",
        new XAttribute("Name", name)
        );

    myxml.Add(newWorkSheet);


    ClearValue(XBookListProperty);
Binding binding = new Binding("Elements[book]")
    {
        Source = myxml,
        Mode = BindingMode.Default          
    };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, XBookListProperty, binding);
    return true;
}
```